# How do I build this `class decorator`?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

I am making a simple decorator that outputs the returned value in uppercase. This is the code I tried:

```
class UpperDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func, msg):
        self.func = func 
        self.msg = msg

    def __call__(self):
        res = self.func(self.msg)
        return res.upper()


@UpperDecorator
def message_app(msg):
    return msg

res = message_app('Hi')
print(res)
```

upon running the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

then I modified the constructor a bit (`def __init__(self, func, msg=None):`) and get this error:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

please help me solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of the decorated function are passed to the `__call__` method, not to the constructor `__init__`:

```
class UpperDecorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        return res.upper()

@UpperDecorator
def message_app(msg):
    return msg

res = message_app('Hi')
print(res)
```

Prints:

```
HI
```